# How to get the Lookup objects and detail object related to a Standard Object

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, soql

i have to delete Account Object record and the cases ,opportunities custom objects which are related to this particular Account ,i have to point these all records(opportunities,cases etc) to some Other Account object record .can any one please guideline how to accomplish this  ??

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question is not clear or you are doing something which is doable from my perspective. You will need to first create lookup fields pointing to your cases, opportunities and some of your custom objects you want to connect. While iterating your account records on a particular condition (say, all of the lookup fields are non-null), then simply get those records in a List then perform its deletion.

You may achieve it by writing a simple or Schedulable Batch to perform the deletion operation.

Is that answers your question?

Just write this query from the start() method of the Batch:

```
List<Account> accList = [SELECT id, oppLookup, caseLookup, customObj1, customObj2 FROM Account where oppLookup <> NULL and caseLooup <> NULL and customObj1<>NULL and customObj2 <> NULL];
```

then in the execute() method extracting the records from the List named scope parameter perform their deletion.